# PyAutoGui throwing KeyError: 'DISPLAY' error

Tags: python, linux, import, pyautogui

I want to automate a windows task and from searching the web PyAutoGui seems to be the right tool for it.
Im working on a virtual env , using python 3.6.9, and a ubuntu WSL.
after installing it with :

```
pip install pyautogui
```

I get this error after importing

```
     >>> import pyautogui
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/mnt/c/GitHub/dad/project_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 241, in 
    import mouseinfo
  File "/mnt/c/GitHub/dad/project_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mouseinfo/__init__.py", line 223, in 
    _display = Display(os.environ['DISPLAY'])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'DISPLAY'
```

after few failing attempts I`ve tried installing PyWin as well , and got another kind of error.
I also tried to define

```
`DISPLAY=:0 python`
```

but still failed.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs while you try to execute in a terminal with no interface, you need to point to a interface inside your system.

You can locate a session by:

```
ps aux
```

and execute your script pointing to your interface like:

```
python3.9 main.py -- :1 vt7
```